# lHow to create Crystal Report by code in Asp.Net

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net

I want to create a crystal report in asp.net with c# use through parameterized query by coding (not by wizard).

Comment: Which versions of Crystal and dotNET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create Crystal Reports on the Fly using ASP.NET](http://aspalliance.com/661).

> I will show you how to dynamically
>   create new looking reports by using an
>   existing report.  I consider that
>   close to creating reports on the fly.